# Show whether the record is find by Name or EmpID

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, ado.net

```
using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
{
    myDatabaseConnection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select EmpID, Name from Employee WHERE EmpID = @EmpID OR Name = @Name ", myDatabaseConnection))
    {
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", textBox1.text);
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.text);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];  
    }
}
```

Sample database

```
EmpID          Name
4001           Johnny Bravo
4002           Bruce Smith
4003           Vince Walker
```

When I type 4001 on the textBox1 this is the result

```
EmpID          Name
4001           Johnny Bravo
```

And when I type Bruce Smith on the textBox1 this is the result

```
EmpID          Name
4002           Bruce Smith
```

What I need is to show whether the record is find by EmpID or Name. For example I type 4003 the textbox or label, etc will be like "The record is found by EmpID" . And when I type Vince Walker it will be like "The record is found by Name" .

Comment: You might want to use SQL parameters or else you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 6):

First off, you have a SQL injection vulnerability that **you need to fix.**  [This article](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries) should get you stared on parameterized queries.

Secondly, you could slip a case statement into your query to indicate which value matched.  Example:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EmpID = @EmpId 
           THEN 1 
           ELSE 0
       END AS MatchedEmpId
FROM Whatever
```

Comment: Oh ! It's been a long day :) Yes totally, this should work :) +1, mate

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Abe Miessler's answer, a quick tip -> use parameterized queries:

```
using (var mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select EmpID, Name from Employee WHERE EmpID = @EmpID OR Name = @Name", myDatabaseConnection))
{
    mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", textBox1.text);
    // etc..
}
```

It protects you against SQL Injections, and as a bonus you get proper value parsing.